# composed look error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, composed-looks

when i try to change the composed look of the site collection, I got this error:

> Could not save the background image to folder:
>   _catalogs/theme/Themed/9577847E. Unexpected error. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied.      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.HandleAccessDenied(Exception
>   ex)      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.PutFile(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object punkFile, Int64 cbFile,
>   Object punkSPFileMgr, Object punkFFM, SPFileSaveParams sfsp,
>   SPFileInfo& pFileProps, UInt32& pdwVirusCheckStatus, String&
>   pVirusCheckMessage, String& pEtagReturn, Byte& piLevel, Int32&
>   pbIgnoredReqProps)

I checked the folders under : `_catalogs/theme/Themed/` and it's empty, 
What should i do to get the right permissions ? 
to to solev this issue .

Answer (score 1):

What permissions do you have on the site? Try to assign with full control permssion.

Try to change the look with other users who have full control permission and compare the results.

Comment: actuallay am site Admin